# ActiveRecord StatementInvalid (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I keep getting the following error when trying to search:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Clients#search

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: client: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "clients" WHERE (client = '')
```

**client.rb (model)**

```
def self.simple_search(search_string)
        self.where("client = ?", search_string)
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="client-search">
    <%= render(:partial=>'/search',:locals=>
               { :my_path => "/clients/search" })%>
</div>
```

**clients_controller**

```
  def search
    @clients = Client.simple_search(params[:search_string])
    render :action => "index"
  end
```

**_search.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag my_path do %>
    <h6>Search Customer</h6>
    <%= text_field_tag :search_string %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

Any chance someone could help me with how I can get around this error please?

Answer (score 0):

Is there actually a column named `client` in the clients table?

By the way, if there is then you could use:

```
def self.simple_search(search_string)
  self.where(client:, search_string)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a column named `client` on your `clients` table. Maybe you need to be searching `name` or some other attribute?

```
def self.simple_search(search_string)
        self.where("{put the column name you want to be searching here} = ?", search_string)
end
```

But in most cases you will need to do something like:

```
self.where("{put the column name you want to be searching here} LIKE '%?%'", search_string)
```

And to take it further, just make it a scope on your model instead of method.

Comment: Turns out i was meant to use "name" instead of "client" for the column. Thanks a lot guys! :D